# dbcollection.find(...) is not a function

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I am trying to fetch the documents from the database using using MEAN STACK with Angular 4. (I am new to this technology) However my router.js file is giving below error.

Typescript:

```
router.get('/all', (req, res) => {
MongoClient.connect(URL,function(err, client)
{
    if (err) throw err;
    var myDB = client.db('TrainingDb');
    console.log('Connectedddd to MongoDB');
    var dbcollection = myDB.collection("SessionDetails")

    var cursor=dbcollection.find()
              .toArray()(function (err, items){
              res.json(items);
          })
            .catch((err) => {
            sendError(err, res);
           });
})
});
```

> TypeError: dbcollection.find(...).toArray(...) is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is mandatory the query parameter in find method. If you want all elements of collection, just pass an empty object:

```
.find({}).toArray(function (err, items){
```